# Cropper is not working on changing the image in cropperjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, cropperjs

I am using cropper.js as cdn link. I can use cropper functionality completely fine on first image upload but when I upload new image, the existing image is not getting changed in cropping section. How can I re-initialise cropper with new data.

**Here is my full code:**

```js
function readURL(input) {
    globalImage = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function readerOnload(e) {
        $('#previewImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]);
    reader.onloadend = (function () {
        initCropper()
    });
}

function initCropper() {
    const image = document.getElementById('previewImage');
    var imgSrc = $('#previewImage').attr('src');
    var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        dragMode: 'move',
        preview: '.preview',
        aspectRatio: 12 / 12,
        minContainerWidth: 400,
        maxContainerWidth: 400,
        minContainerHeight: 350,
        maxContainerHeight: 350,
        viewMode: 2,
        responsive:true,
        autoCrop: true,
        ready: function() {
            $('#crop_button').trigger('click');
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('crop_button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({ 
            width: 160,
            height: 160,
            minWidth: 256,
            minHeight: 256,
            maxWidth: 4096,
            maxHeight: 4096,
            fillColor: '#fff',
            imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
            imageSmoothingQuality: 'high'
        }).toDataURL();
        $('#croppedImage').attr('src', imgurl);
    })
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.7/cropper.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.7/cropper.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<input required id="custom_photo" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" name="properties[Your Image]" class="product-form__input">
<button id="crop_button">Crop</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <img style="width:450px;height:400px;display: none;" id="previewImage" src="">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <img style="display: inline-block; height: auto;" id="croppedImage" src="">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone help me out in this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe just maybe the file format of your second picture ain't right It won't hurt If you check it because I myself haven't used cropper.js I use Jcrop.js

Comment: I have used same file format also I have tried with both png and jpg file format. ANyway I will try with Jcrop.js, thanks

Comment: I have tried with Jcrop.js also but this too have the same issue..

Comment: They have `destroy()` method for that, then again initialize the plugin

Answer (score 0):

To reinitialize it with a different image, first, you will have to call the `cropper.destroy()` method

You can then initialize it like before with the `cropper = new Cropper(image,{});`

Note: If you are using it with Bootstrap modal, make sure you initialize it in the following method

```
$('#modal').one('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    btnUpload.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    cropper = new Cropper(image,{});
});
```

use `one` instead of `on` in the modal shown event handler, as it only gets called once, and it will properly initialize the cropper instance for you. But `on` gets called twice in cases when users may have used modal and may have dismissed it. With `on` you will get `getCroppedCanvas()` as null.